# Microsoft Outlook - The operation cannot be performed because the object has been deleted

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have set up a new IMAP email account in Outlook. It retrieves and sends mail successfully. However, I am unable to delete any messages in my inbox. When I try, I get the message

> The operation cannot be performed because the object has been deleted

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was setting the root folder path to "Inbox"

1. Go to File > Account Settings > Account Name and Sync Settings
2. Set the "Root Folder Path" to "Inbox"

As a side note, I have two email accounts on the same server. One works fine without the "Root Folder Path" being set, the other (the one I'm having issues with), requires the root folder path to be set. No idea why.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: please make your answer as answer

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.